# How do i disabled next select when select after?

Tags: jquery

So i want to disabled form b,c,d,e,f,g select after i choose a with val "after"
and also when i choose b with val "after" then c,d,e,f,g will be disabled
when i choose e with val "after" then f, g will disabled

ex a: after
b : val is after & disabled
c : val is after & disabled
if a: before
b: val zero and not disabled
c : val zero and not disabled
mine doesn't w

its template jquery

```
<script type="text/template" id="long-duration-template">
    <div class='appended-field row'>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Before / After</label>
        <select name="paymentTime" class="form-control time-payment-set">
            <option value="before">Before</option> 
            <option value="after">After</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Due Date</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" maxlength="2">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

then this is onchange to append the template

```
$('#input-credit-tenor').on('keyup change input cut paste', function () {
    var longDuration = $(this).val();
    
    if (longDuration > 12) {
      longDuration = 12;
    } else {
      longDuration -= 1;
    }

    var $currentFields = $('.display-credit-total').find('.appended-field');
    var totalFields = $currentFields.length;

    if (totalFields > longDuration) {
      $currentFields.filter(':eq(' + longDuration + '), :gt(' + (longDuration - 1) + ')').remove();
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < longDuration - totalFields; i++) {
        $('.display-credit-total').append($('#long-duration-template').html());
      } 
    }
  });
```

then this is to disabled function

```
$('.time-payment-set').change(function(){
    var valueSelectCustom = $(this).val()
    switch(valueSelectCustom){
      case 'after':
        $(this).closest('.display-credit-total').next().find('.time-payment-select').prop('disabled', true);
        break;
      default:
        $('.time-payment-select').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  })
```

## inpur

````
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Credit Tenor</label>
    <input class="form-control creditPayCustom" id="input-credit-tenor" type="number" maxlength="2">
    <label style="color: red; font-size: 10px; display: none;" id="total-credit-tenor">Can't more than 12</label>
 </div>
</div>
    ```
````

Comment: which control uses this class '.time-payment-select' here?

Comment: i've been fix the typo @MuthuR but unfortunately my function still not working

Comment: atleast post minimal the code of elements which are using these classes .time-payment-set, .display-credit-total, .input-credit-tenor

Comment: @MuthuR allready edited i give the input credit tenor function for looping the template

Comment: should we disable select or input?

Comment: @MuthuR disable select and set value to after

Comment: set value and immediately disable it

Comment: @MuthuR here is it the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hndlzd/p05yb3c8/4/

after i set credit -> select duration to custom -> credit tenor insert 5 -> then there is 4 appended field -> 

1, 2, 3, 4
if i choose 2 into after then i want disable the select after 2 ( 3 & 4 will disabled and the value will be after)

Comment: made some changes look at this - https://jsfiddle.net/4pd8cwe3/1/